# Find the amount of nuts and bolts produced when $P=500$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A factory simultaneously manufactures nuts and bolts. Suppose that x and y denote the amount (measured by weight in kilograms) of nuts and bolts respectively produced by the factory in a day, with $x\ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$. You may assume that both x and y are real numbers, and not necessarily whole numbers. Production is constrained so that $x^2 + y^2 = 500^2$. The daily profit $P$ is given by $P = 3x + y$.

Part A asked to show that for any fixed daily profit $P$ satisfying $500 \le P < 1500 $ there is a unique production run that produces the profit $P$.

Part B (the part I'm trying to do) asks to find the amount of nuts and bolts produced when:

(i) $P = 500$

(ii) $P = 1500$

(iii) $P = 1580$

Part C requires (iii) and Rolle's Theorem to show that the profit has a maximum value for some $x$ satisfying $468 \le x \le 480$ without the use of differentiation.

Part D asks to determine the maximum value of the profit P and the number of nuts and bolts which produce maximum profit.

Comment: Solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ given $x^2+y^2=500^2$, and substitute into our profit expression $3x+y$. Solve for $x$.

Comment: I get x=0,300. And then substituting x=300 into x^2 + y^2 = 500^2, y=400. Is this correct, or do I include when x=0? For some reason I feel like its variable for 0<=x<=300.

Comment: For (ii) I get 400 nuts and 300 bolts or just 500 nuts. Not sure how to do this properly.

Comment: Not sure how I'd do Part C. I mean it would be easy if I could differentiate...

Comment: Actually I got it. It was easy when I looked at what Rolle's Theorem actually stated... was never shown in our lecture.

Answer (score 0):

**Part B**

(i) when *P* = 500,
no. of nuts = 0
(ii) when *P* = 1500,
no. of nuts = 500
no. of bolts = 0
(iii.) When *P* = 1580 there are two production runs:
Production Run 1:
no. of nuts = 480
no. of bolts = 140
Production Run 2:
no. of nuts = 468
no. of bolts = 176